# How to manually collect jQuery sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery objects:

```
var one = $("#one");
var two = $("#two");
```

And I'm looking for a way to compile another jQuery object like:

```
var oneAndTwo = $(one, two); // pseudo-function
```

So I could work with it like as I get them with `$("#one, #two")`.

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is using [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
var oneAndTwo = one.add(two);
```

Comment: Also you can use **not()** if you want to remove it afterwards